# Can't select child-element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="description_gifts">
<span>Karla Bed</span><img src="images/exit.png" alt="*" /><br />
<span>Quantiy</span><br />
<span>Price</span><br />
<span><strong>Subtotal</strong></span>
</div>
```

I selected the first child , but I can't select the next span's elements

```
.description_gifts  > span:first-child{}

.description_gifts  > span:first-child + span{} // dont work
```

Comment: Which element exactly are you trying to get to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an `img` element and a `br` element in the way.

If you want to select all the following `span`s use the `~` combinator:

```
.description_gifts > span:first-child ~ span
```

If you want to select the next `span` only, use `:nth-of-type()` instead:

```
.description_gifts > span:nth-of-type(2)
```

Or just step through the `img` and the `br` that are in the way:

```
.description_gifts > span:first-child + img + br + span
```